# Integrate custom assert() with AddressSanitizer

Tags: c, gcc, clang, runtime-error, address-sanitizer

I have a custom `assert()`-like macro that calls `abort()` on failure. When using AddressSanitizer, I would prefer to have the usual nice stack trace printed on assertion failures. How can this be achieved?

- Is it possible to get AddressSanitizer to print diagnostic information when `abort()` is called?
- Is there an AddressSanitizer function I can call to manually print the stack trace?
- Does AddressSanitizer provide a function I could use instead of `abort()` here?
- I am interested in a solution both for Clang and GCC.

Comment: One hacky workaround would be to have an invalid memory access in your `abort` function, that is guaranteed to trip ASAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `__sanitizer_print_stack_trace` from `sanitizer/common_interface_defs.h`:

```
$ cat tmp.cc
#include <sanitizer/common_interface_defs.h>

int main() {
  __sanitizer_print_stack_trace();
  return 0;
}

$ g++ tmp.cc -fsanitize=address
$ ./a.out 
    #0 0x7fe00b381e58 in __sanitizer_print_stack_trace (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xece58)
    #1 0x55a059f7f802 in main (/home/yugr/a.out+0x802)
    #2 0x7fe00aec5b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x55a059f7f719 in _start (/home/yugr/a.out+0x719)
```

Comment: Based on your hint to look into `asan_interface.h`, I actually found `__sanitizer_print_stack_trace()`, which works on macOS. Perhaps this is not always available? You said the API is not stable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hm, nice catch, looks like it's has been added to `include/sanitizer/common_interface_defs.h` a while ago.

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you add an answer? I'll then add a comment to mine suggesting that your solution is preferred.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer, and I will accept it. I would not have found this without your hints.